# Can anyone please tell me difference between skew-hermitian and skew-symmetry?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I don't understand the difference between symmetry and hermitian / skew-symmetry and skew-

hermitian.

In my book, it says that difference between these two is whether euclidean space is real or complex.

In complex euclidean space, T is called hermitian if (T(x).y)=(x.T(y))

and If T is hermitian, then eigenvalue is real.

but in complex euclidean space, inner product is complex number.

How can (T(x).x)=(x.T(x)) be true  without conjugate sign if T is hermitian?

And why eigenvalue is real in hermitian transformation?

Shouldn't inner product be complex number?

Then eigenvalue= (T(x).x)/(x.x)   we know (x.x) is real and (T(x).x) is complex number.

How can eigenvalue be real??

Comment: Note that real numbers can be seen as complex numbers. And note, that the scalar product of x and y is defined with conjugates of y instead of simply $x_1y_1+...+x_ny_n$ in the real case.

Comment: The main idea to prove that an eigenvalue of a hermitian operator is real is to show that $<T(x),x>$ is equal to its conjugate and therefore real.

Answer (score 0):

A real matrix is symmetric if $A = A^T$. A complex matrix $A$ is hermitian if $A = \overline{A}^T$. Similarly we define a skew-symmetric matrix and skew-hermitian matrix. Consider $T: \Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb C^2$ given by $T(w,z)=(iw,iz)$. Then $i \in \Bbb C$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, and every vector is an eigenvector.

Remember that in a complex vector space, we must have: $$\langle {\bf x}, {\bf y}\rangle = \overline{\langle {\bf y}, {\bf x} \rangle}.$$ $T$ being a hermitian operator means that: $$\langle T{\bf x}, {\bf y} \rangle = \langle {\bf x}, T{\bf y}\rangle,$$ and that *takes into account* that first property I said.